# How to deal with an answer which tries to answer the question however has additional spam in them

Tags: discussion, spam

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966037/how-to-find-the-sql-table-name-given-column-names-in-sql-server-2012), there was an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31966378/4436237) (now deleted by the user) which did try to answer the question (although the answer was only vaguely correct) and had a spamming link in the answer.

It was quickly downvoted and the user subsequently deleted the answer.

My question is that in such a scenario before the answer is deleted or even downvoted, it is acceptable to improve the answer by editing it and removing the spamming link in it and also improving other aspects of the answer.

Or we should let the normal voting process handle such answers.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Flag as spam, because it is spam.

Don't be fooled by the first part looking like an answer; that part is usually plagiarised, copied in to evade automatic detection. In this case the spammer may or may not have written the query themselves, but that does't take away the fact that the *goal* was plant a spam link to sell shoes.

Note that the answer wasn't deleted by the user; the answer was deleted because it had accumulated 6 spam flags.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Didn't knew about the answer getting deleted automatically due to 6 spam flags. Good to know.

Comment: I've always wondered if there is really some people dumb enough to bite to these spams... Can't imagine myself searching how to write a query on the web then ends up buying shoes because someone posted a link after the query... On another side, why would they do it if it doesn't works. Sad world.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: it's the google juice they are after. Even though their link gets marked with *nofollow* until the ends of time if the post managed to stay on the site.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard: Well, as they say, you never know when you might need a new pair of shoes...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Don't judge them until you've followed links a mile to their shoes.

Comment: How is babby needs a new [pair of shoes](http://example.com/uggs) formed?

Comment: @ZevSpitz "After that, who cares? They're a mile away and you've got their shoes." (Billy Connolly)